# How can I download a maven package from GitLab with curl or wget?

Tags: maven, gitlab

I have a maven package (`dummy`) in my Gitlab Package Registry that I want download with a `curl` or `wget` command.

Following [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/#download-package-file) I tried:

```
curl --user "username:DEPLOY_TOKEN" \
     "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/666/packages/maven/dummy/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

but I have:

```
{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}
```

The project id is correct.

How can I download the maven package?

Comment: I don't know about gitlab, but in usual Maven repositories like Nexus or Artifactory, SNAPSHOT versions have timetamped names like `dummy-0.0.1-<somenumber>-1.jar`

Answer (score 3):

To download any package, including a maven one, you will need to use the [Packages API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html#get-a-project-package).

Following those docs, you need to use:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/packages/:package_id"`

Assuming the `666` in the description is the project ID, then it'd be:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/666/packages/:package_id"`

but you would still need to figure out the package id.

If you don't know the package id, you can use the [packages API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages.html#list-package-files) to list the available packages in the project first.

The endpoint you're using looks like it's from the [Maven API documentation page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages/maven.html#download-a-package-file-at-the-project-level), which specifically states it's not meant for manual consumption, so it's not the recommended method.

If you need to use that endpoint anyway, (as per the note at the top of the page) you need to follow the [package registry authentication documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/index.html#authenticate-to-the-package-registry-with-maven).

This means that if you want to use a deploy token, you need to make sure your deploy token has `read_package_registry`, `write_package_registry`, or both.

Your curl command would then look like this:

`curl --header "Deploy-Token: <token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/666/packages/maven/dummy/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

Answer (score 3):

Your download script using curl should be like this.

```
GLB_PRIVATE_TOKEN=<private-token>;
GLB_GROUP_PJT_ID="<numeric project id>";
MAVEN_GROUP_ID="<maven-group-id replace . with />";
MAVEN_ARTIFACT_ID="<maven-artifact-id>";
MAVEN_ARTIFACT_VERSION="<maven-artifact-version>"
GLB_ARTIFACT_FILE_NAME="<maven-artifact-version w/o SNAPSHOT>-<file-specific-number as found in gitlab>";
FILE_TYPE=".jar";

echo "Running curl for $MAVEN_ARTIFACT_ID-$GLB_ARTIFACT_FILE_NAME"

curl --header "Private-Token: $GLB_PRIVATE_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$GLB_GROUP_PJT_ID/packages/maven/$MAVEN_GROUP_ID/$MAVEN_ARTIFACT_ID/$MAVEN_ARTIFACT_VERSION/$MAVEN_ARTIFACT_ID-$GLB_ARTIFACT_FILE_NAME$FILE_TYPE" >> <filename>.<filetype>
```

In your case your GLB_ARTIFACT_FILE_NAME would be 0.0.1- < some hyphenated number > .jar